# Service not been injected in Spring controller test with spring-test-mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-test

I'm attempting to build a set of unit/integration tests for a Restful API Server I have created using Spring MVC 3.1.1.

I'm trying to use the [Spring-test-mvc](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc).

I'm relatively new to Spring and hence spring-test-mvc.

I will include relevant sections of my code to give you a feel for how I have structured it:

PurchaseController:

```
@Controller
public class PurchaseController
{    
    @Autowired
    private IPurchaseService purchaseService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "purchases", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public final List<Purchase> getAll()
    {
        return purchaseService.getAll();
    }
}
```

PurchaseService:

```
@Service
public class PurchaseService implements IPurchaseService
{
    @Autowired
    private IPurchaseDAO purchaseDAO;

    public PurchaseService()
    {

    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Purchase> getAll()
    {
        return purchaseDAO.findAll();
    }
}
```

PurchaseDAO:

```
@Repository
public class PurchaseDAO extends AbstractJpaDAO<Purchase> implements
        IPurchaseDAO
{

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public PurchaseDAO()
    {
        setClazz(Purchase.class);
    }
}
```

AbstractJpaDAO:

```
public abstract class AbstractJpaDAO<T extends Serializable> implements
        IAbstractJpaDAO<T> {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void setClazz(final Class<T> clazzToSet) {
        this.clazz = clazzToSet;
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName())
                .getResultList();
    }
}
```

Here is my controller test:

```
public class PurchaseControllerTest extends AbstractControllerTest
{
    @Autowired
    private IPurchaseService purchaseService;

    @Autowired
    private PurchaseController purchaseController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        // Test Purchase
        Purchase purchase = new Purchase();
        purchase.setPan(5412311111111121l);
        purchase.setCvc((short) 122);
        purchase.setExpiry("1215");
        purchase.setMerchantName("TestMerchant");
        purchase.setMerchantType("Airline");
        purchase.setTransactionAmount(new BigDecimal("300.99"));
        
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(purchaseController).build();
        purchaseService.addPurchase(purchase);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAll() throws Exception
    {
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/purchase").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
}
```

AbstractControllerTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ControllerTestConfig.class}, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class AbstractControllerTest
{
   
}
```

ControllerTestConfig:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class ControllerTestConfig {
    
    @Bean
public PurchaseService purchaseService()
{
    return new PurchaseService();
}

@Bean
public PurchaseDAO purchaseDAO()
{
    return new PurchaseDAO();
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManager()
{
    return new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject();
}
}
```

I get the following Error when running my test via Eclipse's JUnit:

```
2012-07-08 16:16:00,017 TRACE [main] o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext [AbstractApplicationContext.java:322] Publishing event in org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@42b307f0: org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent[source=org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@42b307f0: startup date [Sun Jul 08 16:15:59 IST 2012]; root of context hierarchy]
2012-07-08 16:16:00,018 DEBUG [main] o.s.t.c.TestContext [TestContext.java:150] Storing ApplicationContext for test class [class com.app.controller.PurchaseControllerTest] in cache under key [[MergedContextConfiguration@2f8a49e0 testClass = PurchaseControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.app.spring.testing.ControllerTestConfig}', activeProfiles = '{test}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader']].
2012-07-08 16:16:00,019 TRACE [main] o.s.b.CachedIntrospectionResults [CachedIntrospectionResults.java:222] Getting BeanInfo for class [com.app.controller.PurchaseControllerTest]
2012-07-08 16:16:00,022 TRACE [main] o.s.b.CachedIntrospectionResults [CachedIntrospectionResults.java:238] Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [com.app.controller.PurchaseControllerTest]
2012-07-08 16:16:00,022 TRACE [main] o.s.b.CachedIntrospectionResults [CachedIntrospectionResults.java:250] Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
2012-07-08 16:16:00,023 TRACE [main] o.s.b.CachedIntrospectionResults [CachedIntrospectionResults.java:250] Found bean property 'mockMvc' of type [org.springframework.test.web.server.MockMvc]
2012-07-08 16:16:00,026 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.f.a.InjectionMetadata [InjectionMetadata.java:60] Found injected element on class [com.app.controller.PurchaseControllerTest]: AutowiredFieldElement for private com.app.service.IPurchaseService com.app.controller.PurchaseControllerTest.purchaseService
2012-07-08 16:16:00,026 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.f.a.InjectionMetadata [InjectionMetadata.java:60] Found injected element on class [com.app.controller.PurchaseControllerTest]: AutowiredFieldElement for private com.app.controller.PurchaseController com.app.controller.PurchaseControllerTest.purchaseController
2012-07-08 16:16:00,027 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.f.a.InjectionMetadata [InjectionMetadata.java:85] Processing injected method of bean 'com.app.controller.PurchaseControllerTest': AutowiredFieldElement for private com.app.service.IPurchaseService com.app.controller.PurchaseControllerTest.purchaseService
2012-07-08 16:16:00,034 ERROR [main] o.s.t.c.TestContextManager [TestContextManager.java:324] Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@403ef810] to prepare test instance [com.app.controller.PurchaseControllerTest@656546ef]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.app.controller.PurchaseControllerTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.app.service.IPurchaseService com.app.controller.PurchaseControllerTest.purchaseService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.app.service.IPurchaseService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110) ~[spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75) ~[spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
```

Any ideas on why my PurchaseService is not created and injected?

### UPDATE

So I added my Purchase Service Bean to ControllerTestConfig...now I get an error about my purchaseDAO.

How can I add this to my ControllerTestConfig? Does it have to be nested inside the Purchase Bean?

```
2012-07-08 18:30:23,029 ERROR [main] o.s.t.c.TestContextManager [TestContextManager.java:324] Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@56da6bf4] to prepare test instance [com.app.controller.PurchaseControllerTest@df4cbee]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157) ~[spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109) ~[spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75) ~[spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321) ~[spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211) [spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288) [spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290) [spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231) [spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71) [spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174) [spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'purchaseService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.app.persistence.dao.IPurchaseDAO com.app.service.impl.PurchaseService.purchaseDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'purchaseDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
```

I added PurchaseDAO bean to ControllerTestConfig.

### Update 2

So now I'm getting a null pointer exception after adding An EntityManagerFactory Bean to my ControllerTestConfig!

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157) ~[spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109) ~[spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75) ~[spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321) ~[spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211) [spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288) [spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290) [spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231) [spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71) [spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174) [spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'purchaseService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.app.persistence.dao.IPurchaseDAO com.app.service.impl.PurchaseService.purchaseDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'purchaseDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: In your `ControllerTestConfig` how do you 'find' your `IPurchaseService`?  I do not see it defined in there...  Have you forgotten a `@Bean` definition?  Or does the `@Service` annotation on your `PurchaseService` automatically get picked up?

Comment: I have updated my ControllerTestConfig as well as AbstractControllerTest...see above nicholas.

Comment: You are missing datasource and persistenceUnit for your entityManagerFactory bean right?

Answer (score 3):

This will not work as spring-test-mvc does not pick the context configuration from the ContextConfiguration of the Junit, instead you can do this(assuming that your Service beans are being loaded up someplace through ControllerTestConfig configuration):

```
MockMvcBuilders.annotationConfigSetup(ControllerTestConfig.class).build().perform(get("/purchase").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Comment: Thanks Biji. I have a problem with my purchaseDAO not been created now (See question)...this needs to be fixed before I can try apply your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include some `@Bean`'s in your `test` `@Configuration` profile.

Previously you had none, but since your update, I see that you have your `PurchaseService` added.  Well, your `PurchaseService` has an `@Autowired PurchaseDao` which also needs to be added to your `test` profile.

Try adding this to `ControllerTestConfig`:

```
@Bean
public IPurchaseDao purchaseDao() {
    return new PurchaseDao();
}
```

Your `PurchaseDao` uses an `EntityManager` which may also need to be added to your `ControllerTestConfig` class. (I am not very familiar with this portion, so I can't say difinitively...)

Comment: That worked and I added an EntityManagerFactory to my ControllerTestConfig but am getting an NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're using @ContextConfiguration (the TestContext framework) to load Spring configuration, my guess is that you want to do an integration test that involves loading your Controllers, Services, and Repositories from your Spring configuration. However, you're using the standaloneSetup method of MockMvcBuilders, which is intended for more focused unit tests that target mostly controllers (services and repositories are usually mocked out).

Consider using webApplicationContextSetup method of MockMvcBuilders. Here is [an example](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/server/samples/context/JavaTestContextTests.java).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but to inherit the context from `@ContextConfiguration` you need to autowire it in the test class, then after that, you can set it as a parent context of your `ControllerTestConfig.class`.

In my configuration, I separated my persistence configuration to be loaded from `@ContextConfiguration`, and the MVC configuration to be loaded from the `annotationConfigSetup`.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes={PersistenceJPAConfig.class})
public class PurchaseControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ac;

    private PurchaseService service;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        mvc = annotationConfigSetup(ControllerTestConfig.class).
              setParentContext(ac).build();

        service = ac.getBean(PurchaseService.class);
    }
}
```

As the `annotationConfigSetup` does not know that you have an outer configuration, you must tell it directly by setting its parent context.

You cannot inject your service inside your test class, but you can recover it from the context and also make it injected into your controllers. Well, you can inject, but it won't be the same service that will be injected into your controllers. Getting it from the context you pass as parent, you guarantee that they are the same. As I mock my services, this is important.